# Config cgi on apache2

Tags: c++, apache2, cgi

I need my apache web server to run c++ compiled binary files. I've done everything I'm told in different tutorials to set my cgi-bin directory but nothing has helped!

I've added to apache config (sites-available/default):

```
ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /var/www/cgi-bin/
<Directory "/var/www/cgi-bin">
    AllowOverride None
    Options ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    AddHandler cgi-script .cgi
</Directory>
```

my c++ file (`/var/www/cgi-bin/test.cgi`) just simply couts hello world!, but when i ask for this file on the browser, I get the error: Internal Server Error!

Comment: Could you post the output of your test.cgi from a console window?

Comment: Also, what does the Apache error log say?

Comment: test.cgi output from console: Hello World!

Comment: Apache error log is : File not exist: /var/www/cgi-bin/test.cgi

Comment: Try `su`-ing to the same user as apache, and try to run the script in that environment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your test.cgi does not output any headers. It should output a set of headers and a body, separated by a blank line, something like this:

```
Content-type: text/plain

Hello world!
```

There are many more things that could be the problem, but start by adding a "content type" header and an empty line to your test programs output.

Comment: Judging by the "File does not exist" error message, you have some other problem - did it work to run the program as the apache user?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks a lot! And sorry for me being too late to answer.

The problem of not accessing files was solved by changing permissions. But there was an error about the folder name I created `/var/www/cgi-bin/` which `cgi-bin` is an alias to the folder `/usr/lib/cgi-bin/`.

When I put the `test.cgi` file there I could access the file but still an error of `Header Content` was logged in the apache. Which was because the Header should be `Content-type: text/html`.

Comment: Thanks for the update, however this would better written as an update edit of the question rather than a new answer.